# Has any comparative study been made on Jewish and Islamic perceptions of Christianity?

Tags: judaism, resource-request, historical-jesus, islam, comparative-religion

Christians see Jesus as the only Son of God who incarnated as a human being to redeem mankind from sin in fulfilment of the prophesies made in the Old Testament.

The Qur'an refers to Jesus as one of the greatest prophets and accepts his Virgin Birth and Second Coming.

Jews on the other hand, question the divinity of Jesus and consider his as the 'prophet of disaster'. They do not accept that Jesus fulfilled numerous prophecies of the OT.
Although Christianity from its side treats Judaism as its source (Jesus himself having been a Jew in human form), and reveres the forefathers such as Abraham and David, it is doubtful if the Jews reciprocate the respect and the regard Christianity pays to Judaism.

Of course, the political alignment has its own course in so far as Christian, Jewish and Muslim believers are concerned. One is however inclined to believe that in so far as religious belief is concerned, followers of Islam have more affinity to Christianity than the Jews have.

**My question therefore is**: Has any comparative study been made on the perception of Christianity held by Judaism *vis-a-vis* that held by Islam?

Comment: Judaism was first, and sees Christianity as a heretical sect that broke away from mainstream Judaism. Islam was last, and sees Christianity as having being given an incomplete version of truth, which was suitable for the time but which is now superseded by Islam. These views are from completely opposite positions, so there is very little to compare.

Comment: Question is okay, but WAAAAY too broad.  There are tons of scholarship done already, so you need to be more specific on **which angle of study** rather than generic "perception" of generic Christianity of an unspecified period.  Not to mention that different strands of Judaism / Islam from different localities and historical periods would see Christianity of various denominations differently.

Comment: Thanks, GratefulDisciple. Independent studies, of course, are available on r the Net. What I am looking for is a comparative study . For instance: to the question whether Jesus is a prophet of God, Judaism would say NO and Islam, YES. Whether Jesus died on the cross would be answered with  YES by Judaism and NO by Islam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Introduction:*** It was not until the Middle Ages that the status of Christianity (and of Islam) as a rival religion was considered from the Jewish point of view.  Today, on the scholarly level, there have been Jewish investigations into the Jewish background of Christianity, but in a purely objective way with the theological questions seen as irrelevant to scholarship.

***This is a brief overview from the article [Jewish Views on Christianity]***(https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/jewish-views-on-christianity/)

The main issue Judaism has with Christianity is that Judaism denies that the Messiah had come in the person of Jesus and especially takes issue with the doctrine of the Incarnation and the Trinity.

Close to that is the view that Christianity (but not Islam) is an idolatrous faith based on the worship of the Cross; to bow before an icon or a crucifix was held to be akin to bowing to idols. Since it is forbidden to mention the name of an idol, a Jew may refer to Jesus but never use the name Christ.

Another issue is the strongest opposition on the part of all Jews, Orthodox, Conservative, and Reform, to the attempts by Christian missionary groups to convert Jews to Christianity. The Jews for Jesus movement has been condemned by all faithful Jews as trying to introduce Christianity to Jews through the back door, so to speak.

***This is a brief overview of the article [Jewish Views on Islam]***(https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/jewish-views-on-Islam/)

Islam is perceived as a religion just as monotheistic as its mother religion (Judaism).  Although Islam was heresy, this did not stop Maimonides (1135-1204) from expressing a positive view about Islam–or even about Christianity, which he considered to be idolatry. In his mind, although Islam and Christianity are both in error, they still have some value in that they prepare the world eventually to accept the true religion, namely Judaism.

> All those words of Jesus of Nazareth and of this Ishmaelite [i.e., Muhammad] who arose after him are only to make straight the path for the messianic king and to prepare the whole world to serve the Lord together. As it is said: ‘For then I will change the speech of the peoples to a pure speech so that all of them shall call on the name of the Lord and serve him with one accord’ (Zephaniah 3:9).

> Indeed, it was Maimonides’ son, Rabbi Abraham, who took his father’s view to its logical conclusion when he argued that, although Islamic religious practices should not be imitated, strictly speaking they do not fall under the biblical prohibition of following the ways of the Gentiles. This is so simply because “Muslims are monotheists who abhor idolatry.

***Summary:*** The talmudic view is that any Gentile religious system is illicit and the only alternatives for Gentiles are conversion or observance of the Seven Laws of Noah which, by definition, exclude any other religious system [Laws of Kings 10:9].

Comment: Thanks, Lesley. Please also throw light on the points of perception that Islam has on Christianity, and how they stand against Talmudic viewpoints. Focus of the Question is Christianity on  the receiving end.

Comment: Will do - but that will take me another 24 hours or so.  Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: That will be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**My previous answer** touched on how Rabbinic Judaism views Islam and Christianity.  You have now asked for the Islamic perception of Christianity, and how they stand against Talmudic viewpoints.  [Talmud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud) is the body of Jewish civil and ceremonial law and legend comprising the Mishnah and the Gemara. There are two versions of the Talmud: the Babylonian Talmud (which dates from the 5th century AD but includes earlier material) and the earlier Palestinian or Jerusalem Talmud.  I am unable to comment on what Islam thinks of Talmud.

The best I can do is to present a summary of the Muslim view of Christianity, and what Islam believes about the end times when Jesus returns as a follower of Muhammad.  That will provide an insight into what Islam believes with regard to any religious group that rejects Muhammad and Allah.

**Islamic Perspective of Christianity and Jesus (Isa):**

Islam says Christianity is not monotheistic and the Trinity is blasphemous.  They also say that Christians worship the cross.  Any form of image or worship of images is blasphemous to Muslims.

Islam says Jesus was only a man and it is blasphemy to claim he was divine, the Son of God (Allah).

Islam says Jesus performed miracles through the power of God but Jesus was only a prophet. Jesus is a lesser prophet than Muhammad (who is the final prophet sent by Allah).

Islam does not believe that Jesus (or anyone else) had to die for our sins.  Islam believes Allah is merciful and Muslims can earn forgiveness by doing more good deeds than bad deeds.

**Islam says Jesus was not crucified and was not resurrected** – he was taken up to heaven while still alive (translated).  The Quran says that Allah deceived the Jews:

Surah 4:157-159

> <sup>**157**</sup> That they [the Jews] said (in boast), “We killed Christ Jesus the son of Mary, the Messenger of Allah” - but they killed him not, nor crucified him, but so it was made to appear to them, and those who differ therein are full of doubts, with no (certain) knowledge, but only conjecture to follow, for of a surety they killed him not - <sup>**158**</sup> Nay, Allah raised him up unto Himself, and Allah is Exalted in Power, Wise - <sup>**159**</sup> And there is none of the People of the Book but must believe in him before his death; and on the day of Judgement he will be a witness against them.

Please note: The Jews refuse to say Jesus is the Christ or the Messiah, neither do they (or Christians) think Jesus was the messenger of Allah.  Islam cannot have a dead, then resurrected Jesus, because that proves him to be the Christian Son of God and superior to Muhammad.  Ergo, Jesus did not die.

**Islam says Jesus will come back as a follower of Muhammad and will kill all those who refuse to submit to Islam.**  In the Hadith (the Traditions) Jesus is said to play a very important role for the end times.  He will kill the Dajjal (the leader of the Jews), live for a period of time and then die a natural death and be buried with the Prophet according to the Ulama of the Ahlus (Fathul - Bari & Ashratus - Sa'ah). Please note that different end-time views are held by Shi'ite Muslims and Sunni Muslims.

> When Prophet Jesus returns for the second time he will reign as a Khalifh and not as a Prophet, follow the Qur'an and Sunnah and rule according to it. He will break the cross the Christians worship, elevate and spread Islam throughout the world.

I believe this new subject (how Islam views Christianity) should be a separate question.  It is hugely complex and would require massive research in order to do it justice.